# Github private repository not transferring to new owner?

Tags: git, github, repository

My friend is trying to transfer his repository over to my account. I'm a contributor on the current private repository, but I would like to own it on my account. I have the ability to create a private repository with my account status.

When he submits a transfer request, the transfer page only shows [this info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKm89.png). We've tried this multiple times (waiting 2-3 weeks in between tries to see if it will transfer), but the repository doesn't transfer and it only allows him to abort.

Any ideas? Should I just fork his project at this point?

Comment: Did you check this constraints? * The target account must not have a repository with the same name, or a fork in the same network.
* If the repository is private, the target account must have a paid account with at least one unused private repository available.
* The original owner of the repository is added as a collaborator on the transferred repository.
* Private forks can't be transferred

Comment: @RandallValenciano Yes, and all of those constraints are met. However, we're both on student accounts (we get free private repos), not paid accounts. That shouldn't limit us in any way, though. When those constraints aren't met, it usually notifies you when you try to submit a transfer request.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same issue. The problem in my case was that the owner of the GitHub account that the repository will be transferred to didn't accept the request. To accept the transfer, you need to check for an email from GitHub containing a link to accept it.